# SQL Reporting 2008: easy way to share look and feel of reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What is the way to go to share a look and feel of a report among other reports in the same project?

I want to share the layout, colors, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I have worked on, have you thought of creating a template and using that template as the basis for creating reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shankalpesh hints at, templates (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/08/14/60283.aspx) are probably the best way to do this.

If you need to enforce common components (header/footer sections) you might try having a template contain subreports.

Comment: I thought templates were the way to go, but I was lacking some good documentation on the subject. Thanks for the link!